# UITableviewcell not displaying UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i'm using an ViewController that is connected with an tableview and use ExpandableCell lib for expand UITableviewcell.

I created a expandcell with UICollectionview in storyboard but when i use dequeueReusableCell he won't load UICollectionview

[image: Cell display]

I'm using Swift 4 Xcode 9.2

Here is my code at **View Controller**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 self.tableView.register(ServicesCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "servicesCell")
        self.tableView.register(ConciergeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "conciergeCollection")

}

extension ViewController : ExpandableDelegate {
 func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, expandedCellsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewCell]? {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ConciergeCell.ID) as! ConciergeCell



                return [cell]

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return concierge.count


    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {


                cell.displayContent(image: concierge[indexPath.row].image!, title: concierge[indexPath.row].name!)
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.dark70
                cell.layoutSubviews()




        return cell
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath)")
    }
```

**UITableviewcell class**

```
class ConciergeCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let ID = "conciergeCollection"

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


}
```

**UICollectionviewcell**

```
class ConciergeCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var mainLabel: UILabel!



    func displayContent(image: UIImage, title: String) {
        mainImage.image = image
        mainLabel.text = title
    }

}
```

What's steps i can do probably resolve this issue? I don't know if is necessary register uitableviewcell in viewDidLoad because i created using Storyboard

Update: Screenshot of storyboard
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set the delegate and data source for your collection view instance? It might also help if you can include screenshots of your storyboard along with the outlet connections.

Comment: @Pranay I update question with screenshots, where i can set delegate and datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you didn't set the delegate and data source for your UICollectionView instance.

Highlighted in this picture shows they are not connected.

[image]

In your `ConciergeCell` class, make the following changes:

```
class ConciergeCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    static let ID = "conciergeCollection"

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var concierge: Concierge

    func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func configure(withConciergeData concierge:Concierge) {
        self.concierge = concierge
        self.concierge.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.concierge.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        cell.displayContent(image: self.concierge[indexPath.row].image!, title: concierge[indexPath.row].name!)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.dark70
        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

And then, in the following function, before you return the `[cell]` array, call the `configure(withConciergeData:)` function with the instance of your concierge data like so:

```
extension ViewController : ExpandableDelegate {
    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, expandedCellsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewCell]? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ConciergeCell.ID) as! ConciergeCell
        cell.configure(withConciergeData: concierge)
        return [cell]
    }
}
```

Just a heads up, I typed in this code here. You might have some compiler errors if you copy and paste it into Xcode. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works correctly but the only thing i changed was    func configure(withConciergeData concierge:Concierge because it's run properly without it :)